# Simultaneous zoom / Scroll on multiple charts using Teechart HTML5/ Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, zooming, teechart

I am displaying multiple charts in a single page. I have enabled the zoom and scroll on each of the chart using the following code.

```
Chart1.zoom.enabled = true;
Chart1.scroll.enabled = true;
```

I would like all the charts to zoom/scroll simultaneously when I zoom/scroll on one of the charts. I this possible using HTML5/Java script version of TeeCharts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should work as the other TeeChart versions do: using OnZoom and OnUndoZoom events and setting other's chart vertical and horizontal axes min. and max. (SetMinMax) according to the zoomed chart axes scales.

We'll try to add an example of this in the demo.

Steema Support Central.

Comment: We've just uploaded the example to the online demos. Find it under "Other/Synchronize Many Charts": http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/html5/jscript/demos/

Comment: Thanks for your help.Great Charting component, works like a charm.